# Apache .htaccess URL Rewriting

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I would like to change a URL from this:

http://opportunityfinance.net/industry/industry_locator_proc.asp?organization={ORGANIZATION NAME}

To something like this:

http://opportunityfinance.net/industry/{ORGANIZATION NAME}

while still accessing the first url.  Where {ORGANIZATION NAME} can equal a bunch of different names, really anything.

There must be an easy way to do this with a .htaccess file right?

Or maybe it would be better if we changed it to this:

http://opportunityfinance.net/organization={ORGANIZATION NAME}

whichever is easier I guess works for me.
Thanks, you guys here are awesome!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must first capture the query string part with a [`RewriteCond`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond) and [redirect](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule) the client to the new URL

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_SEO} !1
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} organization=(.+)
RewriteRule ^/?industry/industry_locator_proc.asp /industry/%1? [R,L]
```

Now the client requests the new URL and you serve the request from the existing ASP

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !industry_locator_proc.asp
RewriteRule ^/?industry/(.*) /industry/industry_locator_proc.asp?organization=$1 [E=SEO:1,L]
```

The environment setting `E=SEO:1` prevents an endless loop.

When everything works as it should, you can replace `R` with `R=301`.

Comment: I'm confused.  Should this all be in 1 .htaccess file?  Or are we talking about 2 .htaccess files here?

Comment: @SolomonClosson This goes into one .htaccess file.

Comment: Ok, this does not work at all.  I have it in the site root, should I place it in the `industry` directory instead?  And why is there a `?` before the word `industry`?  You have it as:  `/?industry`

Comment: @SolomonClosson No, this should be in the root directory. I tested this in my environment and it redirects just fine. What happens exactly and what does "does not work at all" mean?

Comment: @SolomonClosson It is possible to do this with a `/industry/.htaccess` as well, but then it must be modified a bit.

Comment: I'm actually visiting the Server Administrator today, so we will definitely talk about this!  Thanks, I have the .htaccess file in the root, so once we get this settled, I'm hoping it will work right away!

Comment: Ok, thanks, but they are using Microsoft IIS Technology, and unfortunately, there is no support for Apache at all! :( :( :(  It's an old system they have in place :(  Hell, from what he's telling me, it doesn't even support PHP!  Now that's CRAZY!