# How to rewrite to a script and also redirect away from that script using .htaccess while avoiding infinite loops

Tags: .htaccess, url, redirect, url-rewriting

I want to have all the URLs on my site handled by a single script.  So I put in a rewrite rule like this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule (.*) /myscript.php?p=$1 [L]
```

But I don't want to allow access to my script on URLs that actually contain "myscript.php" in them so I would like to redirect those back to the main site:

```
Redirect 301 /myscript.php http://example.com/
```

The problem is that if I put both of those rules into my .htaccess file it causes an infinite loop.   How do I get them both to work at the same time?

I would also like to be able to redirect things like:

```
/myscript.php?p=foo -> /foo
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using an environment variable is perfectly OK, however, you don't need to manually set this environment variable yourself. Apache provides the `REDIRECT_STATUS` *environment variable* which can be used for this purpose.

`REDIRECT_STATUS` is empty (or not set) on the initial request. It is set to `200` on the first (successful) internal rewrite. Or some other HTTP status code in the case of an error (`404` etc.).

So, instead of checking that `REDIRECT_LOOP` is *not* `1`, we can simply check that `REDIRECT_STATUS` is empty to ensure we are testing the initial request and not the rewritten request. For example:

```
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteRule ^myscript\.php$ / [R,L]
```

(Note that it is just `REDIRECT_STATUS`, there is no `STATUS` variable at the start of the request.)

---

> ```
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !myscript\.php
> RewriteRule (.*) /test/myscript.php?p=$1 [L,E=LOOP:1]
> ```

*Aside:* The `RewriteCond` directive that checks against the `REQUEST_URI` doesn't really do anything here. If the first condition is true (ie. it's not a file), then this condition must also be true. However, it could be optimised by including this condition *first*. This would then avoid the file check on *every* request (including the rewritten request). For example:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/test/myscript\.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule (.*) /test/myscript.php?p=$1 [L]
```

Or, you could include a pre-check (an exception) before this rule instead that halts processing when `myscript.php` is requested:

```
RewriteRule ^test/myscript\.php$ - [L]
```

However, if you do this, then the above canonical redirects *must* appear *before* these rules, otherwise they will never be processed. (Putting the canonical redirects first is generally preferable anyway.)

Answer (score 4):

You can set an environment variable

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !myscript\.php
RewriteRule (.*) /myscript.php?p=$1 [L,E=LOOP:1]
```

and test for that in your second rule

```
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_LOOP} !1
RewriteRule ^myscript\.php$ / [R,L]
```

Never test with `301` enabled, see this answer [Tips for debugging .htaccess rewrite rules](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9204355/1741542) for details.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller This is similar to another question/answer. Please see http://stackoverflow.com/a/15244599/1741542